# UnicodeDecodeError when altering text file

Tags: python, unicode

I'm writing a program that takes in a textfile and producing another textfile where:
1. swedish letters are formatted correctly.
2. All words that are not alphabetic are removed.
3. All capital letters have been converted to lowercase letters.

This is my code:

```
import string

infile = open("unigram.wfreq","r")
outfile = open("bigram.txt","w")

line = "Start"
while line != "":
    line = infile.readline()
    wordandcount = line.split()
    word = wordandcount[0]
    ##Fix å ä ö.
    ## å == √• ä == √§ ö == √∂
    if "√•" in word or "√§" in word or "√∂" in word:
        word = word.replace("√•","å")
        word = word.replace("√§","ä")
        word = word.replace("√∂","ö")
    if word.isalpha():
        word = word.lower()
        outfile.write(word+"\n")
    print(line)
```

And here is a sample of my unigram.wordfreq file:

```
gruppselektion 4
lating 1
Morsing 2
varuhusen 7
FULLT 8
latino 3
mammutsl√§tten 2
f√∂gl√∂mma 1
varuhuset 47
livsnjutningen 1
nedtoning 1
```

When I run the file, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "formater.py", line 13, in <module>
    line = infile.readline()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 2732-2733: invalid continuation byte
```

If I look at the end of the terminal output I see the following:

```
Omgångsstarten 1

nationssplittring 1

Handtvätten 1

Three 47

domherre 1

http://www.dryden.se 1

Getryggarna 1

mineraloljor 21
```

If I find this segment in the unigram.wordfreq file I expect to see the word that generated the error right after mineraloljor (right?), but I see this:

```
Getryggarna 1
mineraloljor 21
MAYHEM 1
avv√§njer 1
tilltrasslad 1
EUROPEISKT 1
```

Right after `mineraloljor`, there is `MAYHEM`. I don't see why this word should cause an error, there is nothing different about it!

How can I solve this error and continue the formatting of the entire file?

Comment: What encoding does the file have? It looks like Python it trying to read it as UTF-8 and fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a simple solution to this problem. I opened my wfreq file with sublime text 2 where I can save it with the encoding utf-8. This fixed the Swedish letter problem all by itself. I also changed the extension to .txt. After that I ran the python code again (with changed file names and å ä ö-part removed) and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the file is encoded UTF-8, but you are displaying it using `mac_roman` encoding.  Here's a test:

```
#coding:utf8
data = u'mammutslätten föglömma'
print data.encode('utf8').decode('mac_roman')
```

Output:

```
mammutsl√§tten f√∂gl√∂mma
```

To read the file properly in Python, use the following to read Unicode strings using the correct encoding:

```
import io
with io.open('unigram.wfreq',encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.strip()
```

Output:

```
gruppselektion 4
lating 1
Morsing 2
varuhusen 7
FULLT 8
latino 3
mammutslätten 2
föglömma 1
varuhuset 47
livsnjutningen 1
nedtoning 1
```

Comment: The exception thrown shows that the OP is using Python 3, which has given him a UTF-8 decoder already but is erroring on incorrect UTF-8. The only way the OP could've got his results is from a mojibaked file. I don't think your answer will help here :(

Answer (score 0):

If `f√∂gl√∂mma` is in your sample file and is supposed to read `föglömma` but your Python script doesn't think it's UTF-8, then you've mojibaked the wrong encoding into your `unigram.wfreq` file.

At some point UTF-8 data has been interpreted as mac-roman then saved as mac-roman.

By saving the file again to UTF-8, you've further baked-in your previous errors.